# recursion subtraction problem from CodingBat.com

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to solve this question from CodingBat.com. - https://codingbat.com/prob/p143900

I run the recursion twice, then I subtract their values to give the final answer. Individually, I and J are getting the correct values, but when I do i - j, the result doesn't make sense.

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
  if(str.length() == 0)
    return 0;

  int i = count(str, "hi");
  int j = count(str, "xhi");

  return i-j;

}

public int count(String str, String match)
{
  int i = str.indexOf(match);

  if(i != -1)
    return 1 + countHi2(str.substring(i+match.length()-1));
  else
    return 0 + countHi2(str.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you treat `rescursive` illegally. You should not use external method or even split a string.

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() < 2)
        return 0;
    if (str.startsWith("hi"))
        return 1 + countHi2(str.substring(2));
    return countHi2(str.substring(str.startsWith("xhi") ? 3 : 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna use:

```
str.substring(i+match.length())
```

suppose your match was on index **3** and the length of the word to match is **2**, then you want the substring from index **5** to the end. 
thus,

```
str.substring(5);
```

which includes the index **5**

though, i don't understand why you used

```
return 0 + countHi2(str.substring(1));
```

because this condition will hold if no match is found, so what is the point of checking for a match again in a substring !!!